# Extract text wrapped in double quotes

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I would like to know what is the best way to extract the text that is wrapped in double quotes inside a post.

I've been using mysql queries with this regular expression:

```
text.match(/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"/)
```

but it looks like, this regex is not compatible with lucene regex syntax.

I've been using this to query elasticsearch but it does not work

```
POST /posts/_search
{
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "/.*\".*\".*/"
      }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one :**

```
\"[^\"]+\"
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?38edm

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work because the lucene pattern syntax a bit different and the anchoring is one of those differences. Actually this regex is quite similar to the one I've been using in mysql queries.  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax

Comment: @user3383545 Hmmm... I see... So basically we have to match it all the way... Hmm... Although I've never ever played with that, would you mind trying this too : `(?:.*(\"[^\"]+\")).+` and tell me if we managed anything?

Comment: All I got is this message `IllegalArgumentException[expected '\"' at position 17];`

Comment: @user3383545 Well, it's all guesswork, I can't know without having something to test. Last guess : Does removing the backslashes ("\") solve anything?

Comment: It is obviously a parse failure with the double quotes but I dont even know where the issue is: `Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
            "query": "/(?:.*(\"[^\"]+\")).+/"
      }
   }
}
]]`

Comment: @user3383545 Try this : `"query": "/(?:.*(\\"[^\\"]+\\")).+/"`